# How can I pass a variable data from one view to another view using NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I am trying to figure out how I could pass variable data from one SwiftUI view to another. For instance, I want to send color variable to myColor in the second view.

I want a user to tap gesture the button to set color equal to red when used and then clicking on "Next Page" will push that color data to Test2 View.

#### Test

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State var color : String
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test Page")
        NavigationView{
            
            Button(action: {
                self.color = "red"
            }, label: {
                Text("Red Button")
            })
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Test2()) {
                Text("Next Page")
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    Test()
}
```

#### Test2

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test2: View {
    var body: some View {
        var myColor = ""
        
        Text(myColor)
    }
}

#Preview {
    Test2()
}
```

I tried looking through Stack Overflow for something similar, but I think I might be asking it wrong while searching. I am very new to this so I could use some help. I tried adding the variable in

```
NavigationLink(destination: Test2(color)) {
    Text("Next Page")
}
```

with no luck understanding how it all works.

Comment: read the **very basics** of SwiftUI and put the `var myColor: String` outside the `body` in `Test2` and call `Test2(myColor: color)`

Comment: You should start with the “Apple SwiftUI tutorials”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to modify your code a little bit since I think you've asked this question mainly for learning purposes. I tried making it neater/easier for you to understand.

```swift
struct Test: View {
    @State var color = "user hasn't pressed any color"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.color)
        
        NavigationStack {  // << `NavigationView` has changed to `NavigationStack`
            Button("Red Button") {
                self.color = "red"
            }
            
            NavigationLink("Next Page") {
                Test2(dataToPass: self.color)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Test2: View {
    let dataToPass: String  // << This is how you pass data to different views
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(dataToPass)
    }
}
```

If you notice in `Test2`, I've added a `dataToPass` property. When you do this, every time you create a `Test2` instance using the default initialiser, it'll ask you to fill in a value for `dataToPass` before you create it. This is exactly what we're doing inside the `NavigationLink` if you notice:

```
NavigationLink("Next Page") {
    Test2(dataToPass: self.color)  // << right here we pass in the data
}
```

You still have a *lot* of learning to do regarding SwiftUI but a good place to start are the [tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-and-combining-views). Best of luck learning!

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still learning, but this did help me a lot. I would upvote, but I need a little more reputation points.

Comment: @deadmirage no worries! Feel free to ask as many beginner questions. I can always help with those and I genuinely enjoy giving explanations for fundamental concepts :)

Comment: Btw, if my answer completely answered your question you should mark it as the accepted answer by pressing the checkmark @deadmirage